# How to avoid jsonObject in JSON response in wso2esb 4.9.0

Tags: json, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

Am working with Wso2esb 4.9.0,
I have a service which selects data from database and gives response in JSON format.

Proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="GetMquestionMobile3.0"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable"
       statistics="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <property name="userid" expression="get-property('transport', 'userid')"/>
         <property name="ModifiedOn" expression="get-property('transport', 'ModifiedOn')"/>
         <property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'username')"/>
         <property name="password" expression="get-property('transport', 'password')"/>
         <property name="PartyBranchID"
                   expression="//FieldValue/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="usercode"
                   expression="fn:substring-before(get-property('username'),'|')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="clientid"
                   expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('username'),'|')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:Getmquestions_Mobile xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <p:clientid>$1</p:clientid>
                  <p:modifiedon>$2</p:modifiedon>
               </p:Getmquestions_Mobile>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('clientid')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ModifiedOn')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="MquestionMobile_Seq33.0">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/mquestions_DataService3.0/"
                        format="soap11">
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <errorCodes>101500,101501,101506,101507,101508,101503,50000</errorCodes>
                     <initialDuration>30</initialDuration>
                     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                     <maximumDuration>300</maximumDuration>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
</inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="MquestionMobile_Seq33.0"
          statistics="enable">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             name="Datalist"
             expression="//s:Datalist"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             name="Total"
             expression="count(//s:Datalist)"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
<filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           xpath="get-property('Total')='0.0'">
      <then>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
        {"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{"Datalist":"Not Found"},"Status":"404"}}
    </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"ResponseJSON" : {"Body" :$1,"Status" :"200","Total" :"$2"}}</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Body"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Total')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </else>
   </filter>   
</sequence>
```

This service gives me the response as shown below

```
{"jsonObject":{"ResponseJSON" : 
    {"Body" :
    {"Datalist":[
    {"ComboValues":"Yes,No","QuestionType":0,"Tag":-1,"Question":"LogBooks","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181535979317,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":-1,"IsFollowup":-1},
    {"ComboValues":"Yes,No","QuestionType":0,"Tag":null,"Question":"MasterRegister","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181536700214,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":null,"IsFollowup":-1},
    {"ComboValues":null,"QuestionType":0,"Tag":null,"Question":"OthersRecords","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181536732983,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":null,"IsFollowup":-1}]},"Status":"200","Total":"3.0"}}}
```

I don't want to see the jsonObject in my response, how can i avoid this in my JSON response and get the response as below

```
{"ResponseJSON" : 
        {"Body" :
        {"Datalist":[
        {"ComboValues":"Yes,No","QuestionType":0,"Tag":-1,"Question":"LogBooks","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181535979317,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":-1,"IsFollowup":-1},
        {"ComboValues":"Yes,No","QuestionType":0,"Tag":null,"Question":"MasterRegister","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181536700214,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":null,"IsFollowup":-1},
        {"ComboValues":null,"QuestionType":0,"Tag":null,"Question":"OthersRecords","IsAVPT":-1,"QuestionId":989181536732983,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":null,"IsFollowup":-1}]},"Status":"200","Total":"3.0"}}
```

DS Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Body xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <Datalist>
            <Question>LogBooks</Question>
            <QuestionId>989181535979317</QuestionId>
            <QuestionType>0</QuestionType>
            <ComboValues>Yes,No</ComboValues>
            <IsFollowup>-1</IsFollowup>
            <IsAVPT>-1</IsAVPT>
            <DataSize>-1.0</DataSize>
            <ToolTip>-1</ToolTip>
            <Tag>-1</Tag>
            <weightage>1.00</weightage>
         </Datalist>
         <Datalist>
            <Question>Master Register</Question>
            <QuestionId>989181536700214</QuestionId>
            <QuestionType>0</QuestionType>
            <ComboValues>Yes,No</ComboValues>
            <IsFollowup>-1</IsFollowup>
            <IsAVPT>-1</IsAVPT>
            <DataSize>-1.0</DataSize>
            <ToolTip/>
            <Tag/>
            <weightage>1.00</weightage>
         </Datalist>
         <Datalist>
            <Question>Others Records</Question>
            <QuestionId>989181536732983</QuestionId>
            <QuestionType>0</QuestionType>
            <ComboValues/>
            <IsFollowup>-1</IsFollowup>
            <IsAVPT>-1</IsAVPT>
            <DataSize>-1.0</DataSize>
            <ToolTip/>
            <Tag/>
            <weightage>1.00</weightage>
         </Datalist>
          </Body>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: please, paste your DS XML response to simulate your scenario.

Comment: Hi Jorge i have edited my question with DS Response,Please check.

Comment: Are you sending in a Soap or Json request? You should use Json path(json-eval($.)) to extract those first properties if its Json. If its soap then remove the application/json property. The Jsonobject is the xml representation of the Json so I think there could be too many transformations going on in your flow. Try keeping it xml in your sequence , apply your logic , send to outSeq then inside there do the tranformation to Json before responding

Comment: As @JavaMastaRSA said the $.Body not work for me, with $. it work, but just showme the first Datalist...With your configuration in my enviroment I can see this result: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 05:02:25 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

f2
{"ResponseJSON" : {"Body" :{"Datalist":{"Question":"Q1","QuestionId":989181535979317,"QuestionType":0,"ComboValues":"Yes,No","IsFollowup":-1,"IsAVPT":-1,"DataSize":-1.0,"ToolTip":-1,"Tag":-1,"weightage":1.00}},"Status" :"200","Total" :"3.0"}}
0

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enrich mediator to remove jsonObject from response body like below.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="$body//jsonObject//ResponseJSON"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

You can add a log mediator after enrich mediator and check the changed body.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In side ESB mediator communications take place as SOAP messages. when you send JSON request or when ESB received JSON response what ESB does in convert that to xml / soap message by adding  tag to prevent multi rooted xml. 
try to use

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

before send / call. this will automatically remove your jsonObject from response. but if you want to convert response to xml from json then you need to manually modify using enrich mediator

make sure json formatter enabled in axis2.xml